# How do I select which Java overload to override in a Kotlin derived class?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to implement in Kotlin an `MyIntList` extending `java.util.AbstractList<Int>`. `AbstractList<E>` defines both a `E remove(int index)` and a `boolean remove(Object o)`. I use the following code:

```
class IntList() : AbstractList<Int>() {
    ....
    override fun remove(index: Int): Int {
        ....
    }
}
```

but this gives an `error: return type of 'remove' is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member 'public open fun remove(element: kotlin.Int!): kotlin.Boolean defined in java.util.AbstractList'
    override fun remove(index: Int): Int {`

How do I tell Kotlin that I'm trying to override `E remove(int index)`? (And where does it get that `remove(Int):Boolean` overload from?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that very last sentence was the clue. There is some compiler shenanigans going on in that it thinks I'm implementing `MutableList<Int>`. And `MutableList<E>` defines a `removeAt(element: E): Boolean` which silently compiles into a `remove` method, changing the name. When I override `removeAt` everything works.